# TravisCI Run flutter build apk Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "gradlew" exited abnormally

Tags: flutter, travis-ci

```
$ flutter build apk
Initializing gradle...                                              6.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                       
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/home/travis/build/stefanJi/Flutter4GitLab/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:
```

Please see full log: https://travis-ci.org/stefanJi/Flutter4GitLab/jobs/517867606#L1599

Comment: resolved! Because some plugin target version is 27, but i don't install 27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed: By install android-27 sdk component for some plugins